# How can iOS Siri display Google search results in Safari immediately?

Tags: siri, ios

In iOS 10, I would tell Siri "Google Boston Strong", and a Safari window of search results would appear. I miss this behavior.

In iOS 11, I tell Siri "Google Boston Strong", and Siri remains onscreen, displaying the first five results. I do not like this behavior.

What can I tell Siri so that she immediately opens a Safari window of Google search results?  I'm not satisfied with the workaround of scrolling down to tap the *Show Google Results* button that Siri displays below its five results.

[image]